Connecting two nodes across tables in \multicols environment
first time asker here. New to LaTeX.
I am currently working on a project where I have two side-by-side tables in a multicolumn environment. I want to draw circles around specific cell contents, then connect the circles with a line. So far I have not found a way to do this. FWIW I prefer the multicol environment so that I can have captions for both tables as they are inserted as floating items.
I've posted a MWE below. I apologize for all the packages. I honestly wasn't sure if something I already had could get me to where I want to go.
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter.}{1em}{\Huge}
\titleformat{\part}{}{}{0pt}{\centering\Huge\bfseries}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{RobotoSerif}[
Extension=.ttf,
Path=/Users/cdale12/Downloads/Roboto_Serif/static/,
UprightFont = *-Regular,
BoldFont = *-Bold,
ItalicFont = *-Italic,
BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic
]
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=1in,bottom=1in,inner=1in,outer=1in,marginparwidth=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, shapes.geometric, decorations.pathreplacing, positioning}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf, labelsep=space]{caption}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[description]{leftmargin=\parindent,labelindent=\parindent}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}


\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|} \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Good X}\\ \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Quantity} & Total & Marginal & \multirow{2}{*}{$\frac{\mathit{MU}_{X}}{P_{X}}$}\\
     & Utility & Utility &\\ \hline
     0 & 0 & - & -\\
     1 & 3 & 3 & 3\\
     2 & 5.5 & 2.5 & \tikz[anchor=base, baseline, overlay] \node[draw, ellipse, inner sep=0.5pt, thick] (a1) {2.5};\\
     3 & 7.5 & 2 & 2\\
     4 & 9 & 1.5 & 1.5\\
     5 & 10 & 1 &1\\ \hline
     \end{tabular}
     \caption{Utility of Good X}
\end{table} \columnbreak

\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|} \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Good Y}\\ \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Quantity} & Total & Marginal & \multirow{2}{*}{$\frac{\mathit{MU}_{Y}}{P_{Y}}$}\\
     & Utility & Utility &\\ \hline
     0 & 0 & - & -\\
     1 & 5 & 5 & \tikz[anchor=base, baseline, overlay] \node[draw, ellipse, inner sep=0.5pt, thick] (a2) {2.5};\\
     2 & 9 & 4 & 2\\
     3 & 12 & 3 & 1.5\\
     4 & 14 & 2 & 1\\
     5 & 15 & 1 & 0.5\\ \hline
     \end{tabular}
     \caption{Utility of Good Y}
\end{table}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}


Have a look at the tikzmark library

Welcome to TeX.SX!

The package nicematrix provides an environment {NiceTabular} similar to the classical environment {tabular} (as defined by the package array) but creates PGF/TikZ nodes under the cells.
Then, it's possible to use those nodes with TikZ to draw whatever rule you want, even between two tabulars.
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[
  letterpaper,
  top=1in,
  bottom=1in,
  inner=1in,
  outer=1in,
  marginparwidth=0.8in
]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf, labelsep=space]{caption}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, shapes.geometric, decorations.pathreplacing, positioning,fit}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}[name=A,vlines]{cccc} \Hline
\Block{1-4}{Good X}\\ \Hline
Quantity & \Block{}{Total\\ Utility} & \Block{}{Marginal\\ Utility} &
$\frac{\mathit{MU}_{X}}{P_{X}}$\\ \Hline
0 & 0 & -- & -- \\
1 & 3 & 3 & 3\\
2 & 5.5 & 2.5 & 2.5 \\ 
3 & 7.5 & 2 & 2\\
4 & 9 & 1.5 & 1.5\\
5 & 10 & 1 &1\\ \Hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\caption{Utility of Good X}
\end{minipage} 
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}[name=B,vlines]{cccc} \Hline
\Block{1-4}{Good Y}\\ \Hline
Quantity & \Block{}{Total\\ Utility} & \Block{}{Marginal\\ Utility} &
$\frac{\mathit{MU}_{Y}}{P_{Y}}$\\ \Hline
0 & 0 & -- & -- \\
1 & 5 & 5 & 2.5 \\
2 & 9 & 4 & 2\\
3 & 12 & 3 & 1.5\\
4 & 14 & 2 & 1\\
5 & 15 & 1 & 0.5\\ \Hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\caption{Utility of Good Y}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}


\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[draw, ellipse, inner sep=0.5pt, thick,fit = (A-5-4)] (a1) {} ;
\node[draw, ellipse, inner sep=0.5pt, thick,fit = (B-4-4)] (a2) {} ;
\draw [->] (a1) -- (a2) ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

You need several compilations.


You can use tikzmark. I'll leave to you the fine tuning.
You don't need multicol, for the job. I provide two realizations: top the one I'd prefer.
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[
  letterpaper,
  top=1in,
  bottom=1in,
  inner=1in,
  outer=1in,
  marginparwidth=0.8in
]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  arrows.meta,
  shapes.geometric,
  decorations.pathreplacing,
  positioning,
  tikzmark,
}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf, labelsep=space]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\splitcell}[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]

% local command for simplicity
\newcommand{\standout}[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[anchor=base, baseline, overlay]
  \node[draw, ellipse, inner sep=0.5pt, thick] (#1) {#2};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering

  \begin{tabular}{@{}cccc@{}}
    \multicolumn{4}{@{}c@{}}{Good X}\\
  \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
    Quantity & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Utility} & $\frac{\mathit{MU}_{X}}{P_{X}}$ \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
    & Total & Marginal & \\
  \midrule
     0 & 0 & -- & -- \\
     1 & 3 & 3 & 3\\
     2 & 5.5 & 2.5 & \standout{a1}{2.5}\tikzmark{GoodX} \\
     3 & 7.5 & 2 & 2\\
     4 & 9 & 1.5 & 1.5\\
     5 & 10 & 1 &1\\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw (pic cs:GoodX)--(pic cs:GoodY);
\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{Utility of Good X}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering

  \begin{tabular}{@{}cccc@{}}
    \multicolumn{4}{@{}c@{}}{Good Y}\\
  \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
    Quantity & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Utility} & $\frac{\mathit{MU}_{Y}}{P_{Y}}$ \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
    & Total & Marginal & \\
  \midrule
     0 & 0 & -- & -- \\
     1 & 5 & 5 & \standout{a2}{2.5}\tikzmark{GoodY} \\
     2 & 9 & 4 & 2\\
     3 & 12 & 3 & 1.5\\
     4 & 14 & 2 & 1\\
     5 & 15 & 1 & 0.5\\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}

\caption{Utility of Good Y}
\end{minipage}

\end{table}

\begin{table}[htp]

% local command for simplicity
\newcommand{\standout}[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[anchor=base, baseline, overlay]
  \node[draw, ellipse, inner sep=0.5pt, thick] (#1) {#2};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering

  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|} \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Good X}\\ \hline
    Quantity &
    \splitcell{Total \\ Utility} &
    \splitcell{Marginal \\ Utility} &
    $\frac{\mathit{MU}_{X}}{P_{X}}$ \\
    \hline
     0 & 0 & -- & -- \\
     1 & 3 & 3 & 3\\
     2 & 5.5 & 2.5 & \standout{a1}{2.5} \\
     3 & 7.5 & 2 & 2\\
     4 & 9 & 1.5 & 1.5\\
     5 & 10 & 1 &1\\ \hline
   \end{tabular}

\caption{Utility of Good X}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering

  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|} \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Good Y}\\ \hline
    Quantity &
    \splitcell{Total \\ Utility} &
    \splitcell{Marginal \\ Utility} &
    $\frac{\mathit{MU}_{Y}}{P_{Y}}$ \\
    \hline
     0 & 0 & -- & -- \\
     1 & 5 & 5 & \standout{a2}{2.5} \\
     2 & 9 & 4 & 2\\
     3 & 12 & 3 & 1.5\\
     4 & 14 & 2 & 1\\
     5 & 15 & 1 & 0.5\\ \hline
   \end{tabular}

\caption{Utility of Good Y}
\end{minipage}

\end{table}

\end{document}


I recommend to use -- in order to denote a missing/unavailable piece of data.

Thank you!! Is there a way to set multiple anchors on the ellipse node so that the \draw command doesn't connect to the baseline, but to the east/west anchor points?
